# GKE isn't autoscaling nodes

Tags: kubernetes

I am running kubernetes on GKE. As I deploy pods my cluster runs out of resources, my nodepools do not scale, even though they should. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Can you please describe why you think the cluster should autoscale? Can you reference the documentation you have reviewed, and specifically outline what you are experiencing in detail? How do you know your cluster is running out of resources? Why should your node pools scale?

Comment: I enabled autoscaling on my cluster, I added the requirements for all my deployments, and then I add a new deployment and it is stuck on pending. I have previously used autoscaling on eks based on cpu usage, but for gke it says it should add more when more resources are needed. https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-autoscaler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to firstly disable Node auto-provisioning and preemptable nodes.
Then use command `k get configmap cluster-autoscaler-status -n kube-system -o yaml` to check the cloudProviderTarget and be more patient it takes about 5 minutes.